# Get a value from HTML with VB or C# and write text file

Tags: c#, html, html-table

I'd like to develop a script or program that gets a value from an HTML page (from a table) and puts it into a text file. I want to use Visual Basic or C#.

I'm really new into this so I don't really know how to start it. Do you guys have any ideas? What could help me to get those values.

I need the hours (37 h).

```
<tr>
  <th nowrap class="item_nm1">Lamptime</th>
  <td nowrap class="item_nm1"<div align="left">37 h</div></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [`Html Agility Pack`](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), which is a C# framework which will allow you to parse HTML documents and act unto them.

[This](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020001935/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/011211-1.aspx) tutorial should put you on the right track.

Alternatively, you could also take a look at [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/), which provides a C# DLL which allows you to build C# web scrapers, as shown [here](http://scraping.pro/example-of-scraping-with-selenium-webdriver-in-csharp/).

Comment: this isn't really that what i need .. i've tried it but it doesent seem to work :(

Comment: @diva: The `Html Agility Pack` will allow you to parse HTML pages and seek their content. The tutorial I linked does something about those lines.